# odd error in C; expecting something

Tags: c, variables

I'm writing a small language in C, and it requires variable setting. I have a variable table set up, but I'm getting a strange error.

```
#define VAR_SIZE 100
typedef struct {
    const char *key;
    int value;
} variable;

variable Table[VAR_SIZE];
Table[0].key = NULL;
Table[0].value = 0;
```

When I run that, I get the following error:

```
stack.c:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
stack.c:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
```

What's going on?

Comment: Also, I am including stdio and everything, just not in example.

Comment: Are those `Table[0].... = ...;` statements really outside a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to write code at global scope.  You can't do that.  You either need to give your global variable a static initializer, or initialize it at runtime inside of a function call.

An example of a static initializer:

```
variable Table[VAR_SIZE] = {
    {NULL, 0},  // index 0
    {NULL, 0},  // index 1
    // etc.
};
```

Initializing at runtime:

```
variable Table[VAR_SIZE];

void init_table(void) {
    Table[0].key = NULL;
    Table[0].value = 0;
    // etc.
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    init_table();
    // rest of program
}
```

If you're compiling in C99 mode, you can also use a *designated initializer*:

```
// The following is valid C99, but invalid C89 and invalid C++
variable Table[VAR_SIZE] = {
    [0] = {   // initialize index 0
        .key = NULL,
        .value = 0
    },
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have statement or expression at file scope. You can only have them at function scope. You need to change your last three lines to:

```
struct variable Table[VAR_SIZE] = { { NULL, 0 }, };
```

When using this syntax to initialize a structure or an array, any unspecified field is initialized to zero as if you did a `memset(..., 0, sizeof(...));` on the remaining part of the structure / array. So you can add field to the structure, it will still compile.

<strike>By the way, in C, `struct` name live in their own namespace and you need to prefix them with the `struct` keyword.</strike>

Comment: Actually if you look at the code you'll see that it's typedef'd. The struct keyword isn't needed.

Comment: If i write it this way, can I add more fields later on?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access it like that inside a function. To do it at global scope like that try:

```
variable Table[VAR_SIZE] = {{NULL,0},{NULL,0}};
```

if inside a function is OK then either do what you've already done or I'd go for a simple:

```
memset(Table, 0, sizeof(Table));
```

Comment: It sets each byte of the memory (to 0 on my example). See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to initialize the 0 element of your array  in a function. 
You can declare and define anything outside globally. But the latter two lines are assignments which can only occur in a function

example: (anything else just like you did above, except for the two lines :))

```
void test()
{
    Table[0].key = NULL;
    Table[0].value = 0;
}
```